# Is the Taylor Expansion a good approximation

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, approximation-theory, error-function, error-propagation

Say I use a computer to sum the first 26 terms of $e^{-5}$ (degree 25), will this taylor expansion provide a good approximation? It summed to $.0067$

To me this seems like a good approximation, but I am wondering why? Why is this a good approximation?

Comment: Do you know about Taylor's Theorem?

Comment: Yes I do, but I am asking what the acceptable percent error is in mathematics, since it is much more precise than say the error in biology. This generates a .5% error

Comment: It depends on what you need, you could always examine the remainder term with $\zeta = \max f^{(n+1)}$

Comment: @Pablo: what counts as a good approximation depends on what you want to do with it. There is no universal "acceptable percent error."